# How to run AppsFlyer SDK Integration Test for a Unity project?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, appsflyer

I'm working with AppsFlyer in `Unity` based on the following documentation: https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/213766183-Unity-plugin-V4-integration-guide-for-developers

I followed the necessary steps but when it came to running the integration test, it just stayed stuck in this screen:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6avh.jpg

Are there any potential things that I might be missing that could cause this issue? As far as I understand, I need to whitelist my Android device, select it in the SDK Integration Test, scan the QR Code, install my project's .apk file and the AppsFlyer should start detecting something.

#### Additional details

Here's the script for initializing AppsFlyer:

```
public class AppsFlyerObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    private const string AppsFlyerKey = /* MY DEV KEY */;

    private void Start()
    {
        AppsFlyer.setAppsFlyerKey(AppsFlyerKey);
        AppsFlyer.init(AppsFlyerKey, "AppsFlyerTrackerCallbacks");
    }
}
```

Regarding the AppsFlyer app, here're the settings I selected:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/etY9b.jpg

I want to test an APK file that is not present on any kind of a store.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried testing a non-organic install with this link?
https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/207032126#integration-43-simulating-a-nonorganic-install

Comment: Yup. Tested those steps out. The logs didn't seem to contain the text mentioned in the article's screenshot. Here's what I got in my logs: https://imgur.com/a/lHL7Mbc Also if it's relevant, on the fourth step I got the message regarding app not being available on the market yet.

Answer (score 0):

If everything implemented correctly, but you are still stuck on this screen - it's very likely you have 'zero plan' on your AppsFlyer account. You cannot pass this test on free plan for some reason.

I've found it after two days by connecting device via logcat and recieving 403 error. You can do same to be sure its your reason too.

Comment: Answer shared too late!.